# Why downloaded file docx is broken?

Tags: linux, yii2, docx

Files docx storage on server, when i download them, it's looks like:

PK########M[�R################_rels/.rels��MK#A

locally, everything is ok, but same code on server return broken files

code:

```
 public function actionView($id)
    {
        $file = Files::findOne($id);

        $show_file = Yii::getAlias('@files') . '/' . $file->real_name;
        
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($show_file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like webserver don't support docx files. Try to set mimeType in options

```php
 public function actionView($id)
    {
        $file = Files::findOne($id);

        $show_file = Yii::getAlias('@files') . '/' . $file->real_name;
        
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($show_file, null, ['mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']);
    }
```